# docment.getElementById('').innerHTML is not working

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, web, account

I have tried to innerHTML a div, the code was working but i didn't remember what i did and he didn't want to work anymore.
Here is the code:

```
onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
    console.log(user)

    if (user) {

        const html = `    
        <div class="account-o">
            <div class="owrapper" id="owrapper">
                <div class="oimg-area">
                    <div class="oinner-area">
                        <img id="user-profile">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="oinfo">
                    Username: <span class="oname" id="oname"> </span>
                </div>
                <div class="oinfo">
                    Email: <span class="oname" id="UserEmail"> ${user.email}</span>
                </div>
                <div class="obuttons">
                    <button id="log-out-user">Log out</button>
                    <button id="sign-out-user">Sign out</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        `;

        AccountSettings.innerHTML = html;
        Account.style.display = "none";
        AccountSettings.style.display = "block";
        DisplayAccount();

        
        function DisplayAccount() {
            if(user.displayName) {
                document.getElementById('oname').innerHTML = `${user.displayName}`
            } else {
                document.getElementById('oname').innerHTML = 'Click to set up ur username.'
            };


            document.getElementById('oname').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
                e.preventDefault();
                
                document.getElementById('owrapper').innerHTML = `
                    <div class="form-control">
                        <input type="text" class="new-username" id="new-username" placeholder="Enter new username">
                        <button type="submit" class="new-username-btn" id="new-username-btn">Sumbit</button>
                    </div>
                    <h6 class="oreturn">
                        <a id="js-return">Return</a>
                    </h6>
                `

                console.log(document.getElementById('owrapper'))

                document.getElementById('js-return').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
                    e.preventDefault();

                    AccountSettings.innerHTML = html;
                    userDisplayProfile();
                });

                document.getElementById('new-username-btn').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
                    e.preventDefault();

                    const NewUsername = document.getElementById('new-username').value;

                    updateProfile(auth.currentUser, {
                        displayName: NewUsername
                    }).then(() => {
                        // Profile updated!
                        alert('Profile updated! You need to refresh the page for better results.');
                        AccountSettings.innerHTML = html;
                        userDisplayProfile();
                        // ...
                    }).catch((error) => {
                        // An error occurred
                        alert(error);
                        // ...
                    });
                });
            });
        };
        
        
        const LogOutUser = document.getElementById('log-out-user');
        const SignOutUser = document.getElementById('sign-out-user');

        LogOutUser.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();

            signOut(auth).then(() => {
                // Sign-out successful.
            }).catch((error) => {
                // An error happened.
                alert('An error happened!')
            });
        });

        SignOutUser.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            
            deleteUser(user).then(() => {
                // User deleted.
                alert('User deleted!!')
            }).catch((error) => {
                // An error ocurred
                alert(error)
            });
        });
    } else {
        // User is signed out
        // ...

        AccountSettings.innerHTML = "";
        Account.style.display = "block";
        AccountSettings.style.display = "none";
    }
});
```

The code is running good but document.getElementById('owrapper').innerHTML in the line 45 is not working. The console.log(document.getElementById('owrapper')) in line 55 show the html in line 46 to 52 but the page shows the html attribute in line 6 all the other code in running good.

Note: some attributes like Account, AccountSettings... have already been declared.

Thanks

Comment: Hello NVSS, welcome to stackoverflow! Can you please post a minimal reproducible example as a snippet in your answer? That should include the HTML, CSS and Javascript that show the problem

Comment: Ass @Drago96 has said: Please refer to [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Use ; at the end of this lines.

```
document.getElementById('owrapper').innerHTML = `
                    <div class="form-control">
                        <input type="text" class="new-username" id="new-username" placeholder="Enter new username">
                        <button type="submit" class="new-username-btn" id="new-username-btn">Sumbit</button>
                    </div>
                    <h6 class="oreturn">
                        <a id="js-return">Return</a>
                    </h6>
                `
```

```
console.log(document.getElementById('owrapper'))
```

```
document.getElementById('oname').innerHTML = `${user.displayName}`
```

```
document.getElementById('oname').innerHTML = 'Click to set up ur username.'
```

```
alert('An error happened!')
```

```
alert('User deleted!!')
```